# Asp.net web services videos or tutorials

Tags: web-services, asp.net-3.5

I am developing an **asp.net web services.**

I am new to asp.net but I want to make a web service in **.net 3.5**.

I want some video tutorial or step by step tutorial that can show me how to develop , test and then publish the web service to use it in another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK- look into WCF. Here is Microsoft's [getting started guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx). Do not use ASMX Web services- they are now regarded as legacy.

What sort of other applications are you referring about? More detail on those might get a more in depth answer.

Comment: i want to use that in an mobile app.

Comment: OK- what sort of mobile app? Mobile phone app, .NET compact framework, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good one: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

**www.asp.net** should be your starting point.

http://www.asp.net/learn/ has tons of videos. On http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/, [video #13](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-231.aspx) is about "Creating and Using an AJAX-enabled Web Service in a Web Site".